# Why am I getting these error messages?

Tags: wget, dpkg

Debian 10

`sudo wget -O protonvpn-cli.sh` gives `wget: missing url`.

`sudo protonvpn-cli -connect` gives `command not found`

I have not changed anything in any of the computer files. I do use a firewall and Tor.

I use protonvpn everyday with no problem, but today, problem.

Also, I can usually set correct time with `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, but today not letting me; doesn't give correct time; maybe related to same problem.

Comment: The `wget` command is obvious since you don't actually give it an URL (just an output filename). The second could be because the `$PATH` that you get when using `sudo` is different from you ordinary `$PATH`, and `protonvpn-cli` is not in it.  Using an absolute (full) path to `protonvpn-cli` may help. The last thing about time seems like a totally separate issue.

Comment: Read https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool/ carefully.

Comment: I have been using those 2 commands repeatedly and have had no problems with them. I have installed and uninstalled protonvpn a few times using the same commands, with no problems. There is no apparent reason the commands should not be working. For example, withing the CL instructions that I have been using successfully before, it says: Once all of the packages are installed, you’ll have to download the script to your Linux device. Use this command :
[code] sudo wget -O protonvpn-cli.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ProtonVPN/protonvpn-cli/master/protonvpn-cli.sh [/code]

Comment: You have _not_ used that `wget` command to install ProtonVPN before. It simply lacks an URL and will not work. You even quote the _correct_ command in your comment.

Comment: @Kusalananda Without question, yes I have, and my 'wget' is up to date. In fact, I just used it yesterday to reinstall - worked fine. I follow the same 'exact' protonvpn tool CL instructions, exactly.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks, I have used it numerous times just as written, never a problem before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling for `protovpn linux install` leads to [this page](https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool/), which clearly says the command should be

```
sudo wget -O protonvpn-cli.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ProtonVPN/protonvpn-cli/master/protonvpn-cli.sh
```

So no, you haven't used

```
sudo wget -O protonvpn-cli.sh
```

to download it, because, as the error message says, it's missing the URL. Without the URL it just won't work.

And if you don't download `protonvpn-cli.sh`, because you forgot the URL, then **of course** you cannot execute it. That's what the error message for the second command says.

So: Read the error messages. Fix your mistakes. Try again.

Comment: Yes, I have used that exact command. You left off the 'h' at the end of 'sh'. Also, in my post, the post leaves off the 'https://' for some reason. As I stated, I have been using this command line for the past 2 months with no problems, including reinstalling it yesterday. Trust me, yes-I-have.

Comment: my mistake. i think i broke it into 2 pieces. :(

Comment: But this command is not working which doesn't make any sense: sudo: protonvpn-cli: command not found

Comment: I reinstalled it, working now. Thanks.